Eigenfunctions of the Fokker-Planck operator for the Rayleigh process
I am studying the eigenfunction method to solve Fokker-Planck equations from Gardiner's book on stochastic processes, section 5.2.5. In particular, I am trying to solve one of the examples proposed in the book, which is the Rayleigh process,
$$\partial_t \rho_t = \partial_x [(\gamma x -\mu/x)\rho_t] +\mu\,\partial^2_x \rho_t.$$
The idea is to obtain the left eigenfunctions $Q_\lambda$ to express the propagator as
$$\rho_t (x)=\sum_\lambda C_\lambda Q_\lambda(x)e^{-\lambda t}. $$
The equation for the left eigenfunctions reads
$$ -(\gamma x -\mu/x)\partial_x Q_\lambda(x) +\mu\,\partial^2_x Q_\lambda(x)=-\lambda Q_\lambda(x).$$
One can show, using changes of variables to transform the above equation into Kummer's equation, that the general solution for the left eigenfunction reads
$$ Q_\lambda (z) =c_1\, M(a,1,z)+c_2\,U(a,1,z),$$
where $a=-\frac{\lambda}{2\gamma}$, $z=\frac{\gamma}{2m}x^2$, $M$ notes the Kummer's function, and $U$ the second standard solution to Kummer's equation.
The constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ should be obtained using the normalization condition
$$ I_{\lambda,\lambda^\prime} =\int_0^\infty dx\, \frac{\gamma x}{\mu} e^{-\frac{\gamma x^2}{2\mu}} Q_\lambda (x) Q_{\lambda^\prime}(x) = \delta_{\lambda,\lambda^\prime}.$$
And here is where I have a problem. According to Gardiner, $c_2=0$ and $M$ becomes a Laguerre polynomial. Indeed, looking at the limits $x\to\infty$ of $M$ I know that the integral $I_{\lambda,\lambda}$ can only converge if $c_1=0$ or $a=-m$ with $m=0,1,\dots$, in the latter case the Kummer's equation becomes a Laguerre polynomial.
However, I have no clue on why should $c_2$ be equal to zero, since it seems that $I_{\lambda,\lambda}$ can converge when I use the asymptotics of $U(a,1,z)$,  both when $x\to0$ and $x\to\infty$.

You crossposted this question to P.SE with a lot less context, making a sensible answer there impossible.
The problem is that you have $a=-\frac\lambda{2\gamma}$, which is presumably meaning that $a\leqslant0$. You say that you have investigated both limits, but you seem to have missed that Equation (13.2.6) says that, unless $a=-n\in\mathbb Z^-_0$, the infinite limit explodes.
The other limit is also bad. In Equation (13.2.15) things still look fine, but if you think about it, the special case of $b=1$ ought to be treated via Equation (13.2.19) instead, and then you see that the $x=0$ limit also goes to infinity.
So, there is no scenario in which the $U(a,1,x)$ is going to work. Hence, $c_2=0$ always.

I agree that U(a,1,x) "explodes" both in $x=0$ and $x\to\infty$. But even if so, they can be properly normalised in the sense explained in my question: the exponential kills the power law divergence as $x\to\infty$ and the $x$ kills the logarithmic divergence at $x=0$. Therefore, I still don't understand why I should discard the U solution in this problem.

I agree with your observation that the $x\to\infty$ limit is sorted out by the exponential, but could you check the $x=0$ limit? there should not be enough to cancel the divergence. Is this a radial equation or is it a 1D problem? I don't see where you have a $x$ coming in to kill this divergence.

the problem is 1D. The prefactor $x e^{-cx^{2}}$ comes from the condition of normalization for the left eigenfunction of the Fokker-Planck operator. It is well-explained in the reference that I provided in the question. Note that this prefactor 'weights' the integral in such a way that the Laguerre polynomials form an orthogonal basis. I also think that there is something that I didn't do properly, but I still don't see it.
